# 2013 resource issue : The name 'InitializeControl' does not exist in the current context

Tags: 2013, resource-files

In the Sharepoint project we have added few resource files and mapped them to Sharepoint resource folder(Delpoyment location-{SharePointRoot}\Resources).

using the below code, we tried to read resource string value from webpart design page(ASCX)

```
asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:ResourceFileName, ResourceKey%>"
```

The code was working well in sharepoint 2010 and but for sharepoint2013 we are getting exception as "The name 'InitializeControl' does not exist in the current context".

please help us.

Comment: I have the same issues and I looking for a solution

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any solution, but alternatively i did it from code behind. On page_load we are calling IntilizeResourceStrings method which will do the same.